# Property 'intercept' in type 'HttpIntercept' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'

Tags: angular, angular6, node-modules

I'm trying to run the angular app. using ng serve, but error is coming
like below:

> ERROR in node_modules/angular-authentication-service/dist/app/classes/http.intercept.d.ts(5,5): error TS2416: Property 'intercept' in type 'HttpIntercept' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'HttpInterceptor'.

Package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "7.0.1",
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.3.7",
    "@firebase/auth-types": "^0.3.4",
    "@firebase/database-types": "^0.3.8",
    "@firebase/firestore-types": "^0.7.0",
    "@firebase/messaging-types": "^0.2.8",
    "@firebase/storage-types": "^0.2.8",
    "@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-alert-module": "^2.0.3",
    "angular-authentication-service": "^1.1.8",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "firebase": "^5.9.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-alerts": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-embed-video": "^0.3.0",
    "pusher-angular": "^1.0.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "testacular": "^0.6.2",
    "videogular2": "^6.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.10",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.9.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.1.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

After fighting with this bug for a whole day, I noticed that I used a different version of rxjs in my lib.  It was 0.0.1 version higher in the lib, than in what was imported from another (self created) lib, which caused a lot similar errors, each interceptor gave the same error, and we had 2 in total imported from that (self created) lib.

Make sure you use the same version of rxjs overall, and this problem will vanish.

Comment: you saved me a whole day. Thank you, that's what I needed!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I am sure, I would have been lost in this issue for hours, if I didn't see your solution here.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and it my case it had something to do with package versions.
The way I detected that is that I checked the infamous node_modules folder.
On some modules I found a nested node_modules and inside them there where different versions for example of angular.
So the fix was to check the package.json for those modules, sync the packages versions
delete the node_modules folder and try again.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. May deserve a green checkmark.

Comment: What is the best way to find where are the different versions? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Mmmm I not sure which will be the best way. Once I discovered this issues what I did was to look for nested node_modules folders and from there you get the package.json and from that json you get which version was different. 
In could be not just one package so I just went one per one until I solve all.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is indeed with difference in rxjs versions. For me, it happened while moving some code from an app to a new lib

Use following steps to fix this issue:

1. Find the exact rxjs version in app using `npm list rxjs`
2. Install same version on lib

I faced issue with v6.6.0 and the version that worked was v6.3.0