# Angular HttpInterceptor - argument type not assignable

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I would like to create custom HttpInterceptor to validate if HttpResponse has status 403 - if so, display a monit to user. Basing on some tutorials I've written the following piece of code:

```
@Injectable()
export class 403HttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

 constructor(){}

 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError((err:HttpErrorResponse)=>{
   if(err.status === 403){
    //display monit
   }
   return throwError(err);
})
);
}
}
```

However still getting

> Argument type (err:HttpErrorResponse) => Observable is not
>   assignable to parameter type (err:any, caught:Observable)=>never

Using Angular 7.2.10 and rxjs 6.4.0

Comment: This answer might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760999/property-intercept-in-type-httpintercept-is-not-assignable-to-the-same-prope

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return throwError(err);
```

to

```
throw new Error(err);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Nicola, I want to explain a bit about what's going on.

Your code right now needs to return an observable that is only the next.handle() return.  It cannot also return something else.  So the way you have it written, the catchError is also going to return an observable of that error.  That is what throwError does.  It comes from rxjs and is a way of turning an error into an Observable of that error.

So removing the return is key here, since you want to handle the error, not return it.

```
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            catchError((err: any) => {
                throw new Error(err);
            }),
        );
```